# How to show file upload progress?

Tags: java, struts

Generally while uploading a file,an uploading type of progress bar is used before clicking on upload buttons in all most all every web.

What exactly we are doing after selecting a file(in that progress bar)

I need to do that using java and jsp or Struts 1.x.

Comment: Do some research. There are many examples available over the internet.

Comment: I have tried it with Apache File Upload API.That are Ok but that were comes in the progress bar picture once we clicked final upload button.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, File Upload starts after you POST the data to server not when you select the file.

I think you want Asynchronous file upload e.g. Gmail

See this : [Asynchronous file upload (AJAX file upload) using jsp and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276916/asynchronous-file-upload-ajax-file-upload-using-jsp-and-javascript)

Also See  swfupload - JavaScript & Flash Upload Library

http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/downloads/list

and also this might help

http://www.missiondata.com/blog/web-development/28/file-upload-progress-with-ajax-and-java-and-prototype/